# Moq difference between Verify() and Setup()...VerifyAll()

Tags: c#, unit-testing, nunit, moq, assert

I was creating a couple of Unit Tests where I wanted to verify if a method is called with a parameter whose properties I was expecting.

So given this very simple system:

```
public class Employee
{
    public bool IsEmployed { get; set; }
}

public class DataStore
{
    public void UpdateEmployee(Employee obj)
    {
        // Save in DB
    }
}

public interface IDataStore
{
    void UpdateEmployee(Employee employee);
}

public Employee FireEmployee(IDataStore dataStore, Employee employee)
{
    employee.IsEmployed = false;

    dataStore.UpdateEmployee(employee);

    return employee;
}
```

I want to verify that the `DataStore.UpdateEmployee()` method is called when the `Employee.IsEmployed` property is set to false. So here are two test cases that I believe should accomplish the same thing.

```
[Test]
public void TestViaVerify()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IDataStore> dataStore = new Mock<IDataStore>();
    var robert = new Employee { IsEmployed = true };

    //Act
    FireEmployee(dataStore.Object, robert);

    //Assert
    dataStore.Verify(x => x.UpdateEmployee(It.Is<Employee>(e => e.IsEmployed == false)), Times.Once);
}

[Test]
public void TestViaSetupVerifyAll()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IDataStore> dataStore = new Mock<IDataStore>();
    dataStore.Setup(x => x.UpdateEmployee(It.Is<Employee>(e => e.IsEmployed == false)));

    var robert = new Employee { IsEmployed = true };

    //Act
    FireEmployee(dataStore.Object, robert);

    //Assert
    dataStore.VerifyAll();
}
```

Given the current code of the system, both test passes as expected.

Now say another developer comes along and accidentally moved the setting of the `Employee.IsEmployed = false;` after the `DataStore.UpdateEmployee()` method. Now in that case, I want my tests to fail because the employee will not be marked as unemployed in the DB.

```
public Employee FireEmployee(IDataStore dataStore, Employee employee)
{
    dataStore.UpdateEmployee(employee);

    employee.IsEmployed = false;

    return employee;
}
```

Now when I run the test:

TestViaVerify         **Passes**

TestViaSetupVerifyAll **Fails**

I was expecting both of them to fail but it looks like for the `TestViaVerify()` method, the lambda in the method is executed at the end of the test wherein the `Employee.IsEmployed` is already set to false.

Is there a way to accomplish what I want with just using the Verify method? And not have to do Setup...`VerifyAll`? If there is none I'll just go with `TestViaVerifyAll()` approach.

Comment: This seems as a problem with `moq`. As you are changing already captured object by reference. Could you try to make a copy before invoking the `dataStore.UpdateEmployee`. My assumption is that `Verify` will fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest it is been more then 2 years since the last time I was updated with `moq` source code. Both `Verify` and `VerifyAll` are based on that every invocation of the fake instance is being captured(include the parameters).

`Verify` will looking for method/property invocation and verifies the captured invocations(with their captured parameters) while, `VerifyAll` will take all the setup methods and do the same as `Verify` method.

Since the captured parameter is `ByRef` parameter and if the last paragraph is still relevant you can cause your UTs failed simply by add `robert.IsEmployed = true;` before invoke `Verify`/`VerifyAll`:

```
[Test]
public void TestViaVerify()
{
    ....
    robert.IsEmployed = true; // will make this UT to failed
    //Assert
    dataStore.Verify(x => x.UpdateEmployee(It.Is<Employee>(e => e.IsEmployed == false)), Times.Once);
}

[Test]
public void TestViaSetupVerifyAll()
{
    ....
    robert.IsEmployed = true; // will make this UT to failed
    //Assert
    dataStore.VerifyAll();
}
```

I think that in the past I answered something similar(with more examples), the way I was workaround this problem is a combination between `Setup` and `Callback` since I don't like to use `VerifyAll` pattern:

```
....
var invokedCorrectly = false;
dataStore.Setup(x => x.UpdateEmployee(It.Is<Employee>(e => e.IsEmployed == false)))
         .Callback<Employee>(x=> invokedCorrectly = true);

//Act
FireEmployee(dataStore.Object, robert);

//Assert
Assert.IsTrue(invokedCorrectly);
```

Answer (score 1):

This is expected behavior in `moq` as arguments captured by invocation are compared by identity, using `Equals` not by value. Once you changed captured arguments you actually directly change the invocation. Then later on when you verify these objects are not the same anymore. As [@Old Fox](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4332059/old-fox) alredy provided one solution I will just add one more. You could use `Verify()` instead of `VerifyAll()` the difference is that the first one will only check setups marked as `Verifiable()`. In your case something like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestViaSetupVerifyAll()
{
    //Arrange
    Mock<IDataStore> dataStore = new Mock<IDataStore>();
    dataStore
        .Setup(x => x.UpdateEmployee(It.Is<Employee>(e => e.IsEmployed == false)))
        .Verifiable();

    var robert = new Employee { IsEmployed = true };

    //Act
    FireEmployee(dataStore.Object, robert);

    //Assert
    dataStore.Verify();
}
```

If you mark setup as `Verifiable()` you could be able to capture the particular invocation with the state of the object you actually expect.